# Subscription in Sensu

Tags: docker

Could you please let me know, what is the use of **subscription** keyword in Sensu check file?
When using Sensu with Docker , is it related to the Docker tags of the image/container?

Answer (score 2):

So for this you have to check how sensu checks work in total.

To start this of we have to differentiate between the two possible check ‘categories’ where there are ‘Subscribers’ and ‘Standalone’.

Since your question is mainly about the subscription and thus the the subscribers, I will leave the ‘standalone’ out of this for now.

How does this work?

Every check configuration includes a one or more subscription groups unless it is defined as ‘standalone’.

Let’s say this is our example check configuration:

```
{
  "checks": {
    "sensu-website": {
      "command": "check-http.rb -u https://sensuapp.org",
      "subscribers": [
        "production"
      ],
      "interval": 60,
    }
  }
}
```

You see that his check is part of the subcribers-group ‘production’.

Now on the clients where you run the sensu-client you will have the configuration for the corresponding sensu-client.

Let’s say that this is our example client.json config file

```
    {
      "client": {
        "name": "i-424242",
        "address": "8.8.8.8",
        "subscriptions": [
          "production",
          "webserver",
          "mysql"
        ],
        "socket": {
          "bind": "127.0.0.1",
          "port": 3030
        }
      }

}
```

You see that there is an array of subscriptions which also includes production.

This means that this client will execute all checks that are members of the subscription group ‘production’, just like our example check above.

For the last part of your question: it is only specific to docker if you structure your checks and their subscriber groups like that.